# Lightning Component output form styling

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I'm trying to develop a lightning component which represents an output form. That is, instead of having input boxes, I just want the lightning text with the underline below and the label on top.

So far I've checked the `ui:outputText`, `lightning:formattedText`, and a few other components and I can't seem to find a way to display what I want without having to write the HTML myself with using SLDS classes.

What's the best approach for creating such an *output form* given that the data will not be coming from Salesforce Objects but from a JSON from a remote call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you'll have to write some of the styling yourself. Avoid the `ui:*` namespace elements, as they are only there to provide basic HTML-level functionality wrapped up in some basic formatting. There's no generic equivalent to apex:pageBlock/apex:pageBlockSection/apex:pageBlockSectionItem, so you'll need to use the `lightning:formatted*` elements wrapped up with the outer-level styling needed to get the appearance you're looking for, or perhaps even just write a single component that wraps up an entire [form element](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-element/#content), plus one more for the [form layout](https://lightningdesignsystem.com/components/form-layout/#content).

Comment: @JavierGarcíaManzano Yes, it's pretty annoying. That said, it's only two basic components you need to write to get a decent-looking output form, perhaps an hour's worth of work or so.